# How to set default value as a populated 3D array and still define the objects within it?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to make a 3d array that will represent years, months and days:

```
[years[months[days]]]
```

And so I made a simple function that does this perfectly, for each day I am populating a default object:

```
function generateEmpty3dArray() {
  // i did that on purpuse with [[]], im doing it just for 1 year atm, 
  // thats why i am using index 0
  
  const array = [[]];
  const months = 12;

  for(let month = 0; month < months; month++) {
    const monthDays = new Date(2021, month + 1, 0).getDate();
    array[0].push([]);

    for(let day = 0; day < monthDays; day++) {
      array[0][month].push({shift: "X"})
    }
  }

  console.log(array)
}
```

The array that is generated is exactly what I want, my issue is in defining the `Person` schema:

```
const personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  schedule: {
    type: Array,
    default: generateEmpty3dArray() //????
  }
})
```

I dont know how to populate the default field, what I want to happen is, whenever a new Person is created into the database, I want him to receive that empty 3d array, so that I can then work with it and set different shifts.

The problem is that, I have no idea how to both specify what the specific value of each day should look like `[[[{shift: {type: String, enum: shifts}}]]]` and at the same time, create the default array for the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked:

```
schedule: {
    type: [
      [
        [
          {
            shift: { type: String, required: true, enum: shifts },
          },
        ],
      ],
    ],
    default: generateEmpty3dArray(),
  },
```